# Expected value of balls left, drawing colored balls without replacement

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

In an urn, there are $m$ red balls and $n$ green balls.

Every minute, you draw one from the urn.
What is the expected number of balls (regardless of its color) left in the jar after you have drawn all red or green balls?

After some experimentation, I found the expected value is $\frac{m(m+1)+n(n+1)}{(n+1)(m+1)}$ for $m$ and $n \ge 0.$

I cannot find any intuitive way to arrive to this formula.

p.s. I tried conditional expectation, p.g.f, m.g.f.

p.s.2 once I found that formula, I could prove it easily using induction. But I am very interested to know if there is any other way to arrive to that formula (maybe just from a pure probability perspective?).

Comment: You formula cannot possibly be correct, because the expectation will be the same when the ball colors are switched, which swaps $m$ and $n:$ therefore the formula must be invariant when $m$ and $n$ are switched.

Comment: @whuber thanks for pointing out, It's a typo, I just updated with the correct formula

Comment: Is this a question from a course or textbook? If so, please add the [tag:self-study]
tag & read its [wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @StephanKolassa thanks, this is not from schoolwork.

Comment: The new formula gives the wrong values when $m=0$ or $n=0,$ so it's still not correct.

Comment: @wuber, thanks for pointing out again, I have updated the formula with constraints.

Comment: Still incorrect: it's no longer symmetric in $(m,n).$ Assuming that's a typo and you mean the numerator to be $n(m+1)+m(n+1),$ it's still incorrect because it gives the wrong value for $m=n=1$ (which should be $4/3$).

Comment: @whuber How do you get 4/3?
When m = n = 1, the expected value should be P(draw red and only green left)*1 + P(draw green and only red left)*1 = 0.5*1 + 0.5*1 = 1.
Pretty sure I got it right this time because if m=n=1, you cannot have an expected number greater than 1:)

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo: I meant $m=1,$ $n=2.$  There is a $1/3$ chance of leaving two balls and a $2/3$ chance of leaving one ball, for an expectation of $4/3.$ If I'm computing right, your formula gives $7/6.$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123190/discussion-between-louis-law-and-whuber).

Comment: Chat doesn't support TeX markup, unfortunately.  A correct formula for the expectation is $$\frac{m}{n+1} + \frac{n}{m+1},$$ which is a simplified version of yours.

Comment: @whuber you are correct, m/(n+1) is the conditional expectation conditioned on right side finishes first and similar for the other one. May i know if you find a way to arrive to this formula?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is interesting because an intuitive approach leads to a quick solution.

**Consider a simplified version.**  Randomly draw *every* ball from the urn, one at a time, and lay them down in sequence as you do so.  The sequence ends with a string of all green or all red balls.  You will eventually get to keep this "monochromatic suffix" as a reward, but for now let's suppose you care only about keeping the red balls.  What is your expected reward?

Look at the sequence you laid down.  It consists of $m$ red balls among which $n$ green balls are interspersed.  These green balls divide the red balls into $n+1$ groups (of which many may be empty).  ***Intuitively,* we would figure each group -- *including the last* -- must therefore contain $m/(n+1)$ red balls on average.**

This can be demonstrated with a basic combinatorial argument, but that isn't necessary.  Computer science teaches us it can be *much* easier to check the solution to a problem than to produce it in the first place.  Therefore, let's immediately check this guess to see whether it needs any correcting.

**The check is done by mathematical induction on the number of balls in the urn, $N=m+n.$**  The formula is correct when the urn is empty; that is, when $N=m+n=0$ it gives the right answer $0/(0+1)=0.$  Suppose now the formula happens to be true for $N \ge0.$  The formula clearly is correct when $m=0$ or $n=0,$ because in either case you will keep all the red balls in the urn and the formula counts them.  So, suppose both $m$ and $n$ are nonzero.  We only need to show the formula holds for all the other possible values with $m+n=N;$ that is, $m=1,2,\ldots,N-1$ and $n=N-m.$

The expected reward $f(m,n),$ by definition, is the expected reward after drawing a red ball times the chance of drawing a red ball, *plus* the expected reward after drawing a green ball times the chance of drawing a green ball:

$$f(m,n) = f(m-1,n)\left(\frac{m}{m+n}\right) + f(m,n-1)\left(\frac{n}{m+n}\right) .$$

Since both $(m-1)+n$ and $m+(n-1)$ are less than $N,$ and we have assumed the formula holds in such cases, we may plug it into the forgoing equation to produce

$$f(m,n) =\frac{m-1}{n+1} \left(\frac{m}{m+n}\right) + \frac{m}{(n-1)+1}\left(\frac{n}{m+n}\right)  = \frac{m}{n+1},$$

*QED.*

The analysis for the green balls is identical: just swap the colors, which swaps $m$ and $n.$  Thus, **the total reward for both red and green balls is**

> $$f(m,n) + f(n,m) = \frac{m}{n+1} + \frac{n}{m+1}.$$

Comment: the intuition mentioned is quite interesting, thanks for the answer

Comment: But what are the assumptions behind this intuition.
If we change the problem a bit, let's say the urn is now transparent, every time we draw, we pick one colour at random, so there is 50% chance draw red/green. In this case, the answer should be different and how this intuition apply?

Comment: The basis for the intuition is that under the original rules, you are sampling without replacement,. whence every sequence is equally probable.  When you change the rules you will need to reconsider those probabilities.