# Expected value of balls left, drawing colored balls with 0.5 probability

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, negative-binomial-distribution

In an urn, there are m red balls and n green balls.

Every minute, you toss a coin and decide which color to draw, then remove one ball of that color from the urn. (e.g. remove one green ball if it is a tail)

What is the expected number of balls left in the jar after you have drawn all red or green balls?

Note that 0 <= m+n <= 10^5
And the solution should be implemented in a way that it return results within 5 second using 1 CPU and 1GB ram.

p.s. this is an interview question I found online (from some interview question banks), tried to attack this problem using binomial / negative-binomial distribution but no luck so far

Comment: Have you got any details about the coin? Is it fair?

Comment: Yes, it's a fair coin @Spätzle

Comment: How does it differ from your previous question? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/520599/expected-value-of-balls-left-drawing-colored-balls-without-replacement

Comment: @Spätzle, in this question, any ball is removed with 0.5 probability every round because of the fair coin

Comment: There's a connection to the negative binomial but it's not itself negative binomial. It's conceptually straightforward to write a loop that "pushes" probabilities from the starting state towards the  stopping states if you just need a numeric calculation.

Comment: @Glen_b not sure what you mean by starting state and stopping state?

Comment: At the start, you have m red balls and n green balls; that's your starting state. At the end you have *either* 0 red and some nonzero number of green ball between 1 and n, *or* 0 green and some nonzero number of red between 1 and m (i.e. m+n stopping states). Imagine first simulating the process -- you progress from m red and n green to either m-1 red and n green or to m red and n-1 green, pushing the state progressively toward the set of stopping states. Now instead of moving the state repeatedly toward the stopping states, simply move its *probability*, which begins all in the start state...

Comment: and progressively reallocate that instead (once!) through the states. Now the naive approach would have a large m by n matrix and progress through the whole thing, but I believe you can with a little effort reduce that to O(m+n), and at the same time "shortcut" the calculations somewhat and fit within those requirements. Of course, additional thought may reduce the whole thing more dramatically.

Comment: @Glen_b I do have a somewhat similar solution, but it doesn't fit under the computation constraint

Comment: You should probably outline your ideas in the question so that people aren't wasting their time explaining the parts that are already obvious to you.

Comment: basically I cannot found a way to reduce it to O(m+n) or any "shortcut" you mentioned above, and seems this is the key part of this question

Answer (score 1):

So you've got $m$ red balls and $n$ green balls. As the coin is fair, $P(Green)=P(Red)=0.5$.

Assume we've had $k$ draws, the probability of drawing $g$ greens and $k-g$ reds is
$P(k,g)={k \choose g}0.5^{k}$, and the number of balls left in the urn is $m+n-k$. The expected value of balls left in the urn (given one color is completely out) is then:

$$\sum_{k=n}^{n+m-1}{(m+n-k){k \choose n}0.5^k}+\sum_{k=m}^{n+m-1}{(m+n-k){k \choose m}0.5^k}$$

So if you're going to solve this numerically, write two loops and you're good.

But wait a second, what if $k$ is too large for a factorial computation? or we fear it might be too slow? This is where the [normal approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Normal_approximation) becomes handy.
As $p=0.5$ it is proper for any $k \geq 10$, according to the $3\sigma$ rule of thumb. The derivation of the expected number of balls left is very simple.

So, overall, your function should condition of the size of the input: if $m,n<10$ you should sum using the formula above; otherwise, solve using the normal.

Comment: These sums have closed formulas ;-).

Comment: yes @whuber I suppose so but I did not find them quickly enough and in any way the normal approximation should do it. I believe this should be a variant of $\sum_{k}{k{n \choose k}}=n2^{n-1}$ but I didn't get the proper maneuver when writing.

Comment: The problem is that when $n+m$ is large, such as $10^5$ (as in the question), the terms in the sums will overflow and underflow, so some kind of simplification is needed.

Comment: That's why I've referred to the normal approximation

Comment: That's a good point.  It would be a stronger one if you could indicate how accurate that approximation is likely to be (as a function of $m$ and $n,$ potentially).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the normal approximation is a great idea and indeed it should be good enough and works in practice
@whuber do you think it is possible to have a closed formulas for those sums? I spent days trying to crack it but still no luck, hope you could shed some lights on it